# How to wait until page load without browser stopped respnding?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using C# I was trying to pause execution until the page load after login so I used this code:

```
    for (int second = 0; ; second++)
    {
        if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
        try
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("footer")).Displayed) break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

But I get system error that the browser Firefox stopped responding apparently on the Thread.Sleep(1000); line so how I prevent that ?

is there another way to pause execution other than thread.sleep() ?

**Edit**:
I used now

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

but it execute inconstantly without waiting 10 seconds !! why ??

Comment: If Firefox stops responding, this has nothing to do with 'Thread.Sleep(1000);'

Comment: when I comment sleep() I dont get the stop responding error

Answer (score 0):

One soultion is using a custom `WebDriverWait` with an expected condition like `titleIs'. This means the driver will poll the page for a predefined amount of time waiting for the page title to match what you expect it to be. In Java it would be like so:

```
public Boolean waitForPageIsLoaded(String title) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(title));
}
```

Comment: same problem under windows 10. I wrote 20 seconds but it executes instantly without any wait !!

Comment: I tried  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); but it execute instantly without wait !! why ?